# Getting Bad request error when I am trying to upload file to One drive using Delphi

Tags: delphi, onedrive

I am trying to upload files to one drive using RestAPI in Delphi. But unable to upload files into one Drive. Authentication to one drive succeeded but getting error while uploading files. Below is the error message I am getting.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cGdf5.png)

```
edt_OneDrive_AuthCode := '';
    edt_OneDrive_AccessToken := '';
    edt_OneDrive_RefreshToken := '';
    edt_OneDrive_ClientID:= '********'     ;
    edt_OneDrive_ClientSecret:='*********';
    edt_OneDrive_RedirectURI:='https://login.live.com/oauth20_desktop.srf';

    LURL := 'https://login.live.com/oauth20_authorize.srf';
    LURL := LURL + '?response_type=' + URIEncode('code');
    LURL := LURL + '&client_id=' + URIEncode(edt_OneDrive_ClientID);
    LURL := LURL + '&redirect_uri=' + URIEncode(edt_OneDrive_RedirectURI);
    LURL := LURL + '&scope=' + URIEncode('wl.basic wl.signin wl.skydrive wl.skydrive_update onedrive.readwrite');

   ///1.Get authorizationCode
     wv := Tfrm_OAuthWebForm.Create(self);
    try
      wv.OnTitleChanged := self.OAuth2_GoogleTasks_BrowserTitleChanged;
      wv.ShowModalWithURL(LURL);
    finally
      wv.Release;
    end;

    {ResetRESTComponentsToDefaults; }
    /// step #2: get the access-token using authorizationCode

   { ResetRESTComponentsToDefaults;}
    RESTClient:=TRESTClient.Create(nil);
    RESTClient.BaseURL := 'https://login.live.com/';     {' https://apis.live.net/v5.0/';  }

  RESTRequest := TRESTRequest.Create(nil);

    RESTRequest.Method := TRESTRequestMethod.rmPOST;
    RESTRequest.Resource := 'oauth20_token.srf';///https://login.live.com/oauth20_token.srf?pretty=false
    RESTRequest.Client:=   RESTClient;

    ///RESTRequest.Params.AddHeader('Content-Type', TRESTContentType.ctAPPLICATION_X_WWW_FORM_URLENCODED);
    ///RESTRequest.Params.AddHeader('Content-Type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded');
    ///RESTRequest.ContentType:= TRESTContentType.ctAPPLICATION_X_WWW_FORM_URLENCODED;
    /// RESTRequest.Params.AddHeader('Content-Type', TRESTContentType.ctAPPLICATION_X_WWW_FORM_URLENCODED);
     ///RESTRequest.Params.AddHeader('Content-Type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded');

    {RESTRequest.ContentType:=  'application/x-www-form-urlencoded';   }

    { _options.ClientId, _options.ClientSecret, _options.CallbackUrl, authorizationCode }
    RESTRequest.Params.AddItem('code', edt_OneDrive_AuthCode, TRESTRequestParameterKind.pkGETorPOST);
    RESTRequest.Params.AddItem('client_id', edt_OneDrive_ClientID, TRESTRequestParameterKind.pkGETorPOST);
    RESTRequest.Params.AddItem('client_secret', edt_OneDrive_ClientSecret, TRESTRequestParameterKind.pkGETorPOST);
    RESTRequest.Params.AddItem('redirect_uri',edt_OneDrive_RedirectURI , TRESTRequestParameterKind.pkGETorPOST);
    RESTRequest.Params.AddItem('grant_type', 'authorization_code', TRESTRequestParameterKind.pkGETorPOST);



    RESTRequest.Execute;

    OAuth2_OneDrive:=TOAuth2Authenticator.Create(nil);

    if RESTRequest.Response.GetSimpleValue('access_token', LToken) then
      OAuth2_OneDrive.AccessToken := LToken;
    if RESTRequest.Response.GetSimpleValue('refresh_token', LToken) then
      OAuth2_OneDrive.RefreshToken := LToken;

           {$IF DEFINED(MsWindows)}
      local_filename :=  'C:\Users\mahesh.daram\Desktop\a.txt';

     {$ENDIF}
//      RESTResponseDataSetAdapter.AutoUpdate := false;

      RESTRequest.Params.Clear;
      RESTRequest.ClearBody;
      RESTRequest.Method := TRestRequestMethod.rmPOST;




      //RESTClient.Authenticator:=OAuth2_OneDrive;
      ///
      RESTClient := TRESTClient.Create('https://api.onedrive.com/v1.0');

        RESTClient.Authenticator :=OAuth2_OneDrive ;

         ///
      //RESTClient.BaseURL :=     'https://api.onedrive.com/v1.0';
      RESTRequest.Resource:='/drive/items/root:/a.txt';
//      RESTRequest.Resource:='/drive/items/root:/a.txt:/content';
      RESTRequest.Client:= RESTClient;
      upload_stream := TFileStream.Create(local_filename,fmOpenRead);
      upload_stream.Position := 0;
                             //Set Content-Type to text/plain
  //Set Request Body to FileStream
    RESTRequest.ClearBody;


        RESTRequest.Addbody(upload_stream, TRESTContentType.ctAPPLICATION_OCTET_STREAM);


                           RESTRequest.Execute;//Getting exception here
```

We are getting exception at last line (RESTRequest.Execute). Can any body suggest how to solve this issue?

Comment: You should change your applications ClientSecret value, this value's security is compromised when it known by outsiders.

Answer (score 2):

To interact with files on OneDrive you should be using the `https://api.onedrive.com` base url.

To perform an upload you would construct a url like the following, and then PUT the file content into that location.  There are more upload options that might fit your application's scenario better, learn about them [here](https://dev.onedrive.com/items/upload.htm).

`https://api.onedrive.com/v1.0/drive/root:/{parent-path}/{filename}:/content`

The OneDrive API is documented at https://dev.onedrive.com/ for all manor of scenarios around interacting with the metadata from OneDrive as well as uploading and downloading.

Comment: We are getting exception while retrieving access token from one drive. We commented with "//Getting Exception here" comment. Can you please suggest what is the issue.